# How to distinguish one data set to the other using PCA

Tags: pca

I have 5 set data, each for different observations, i.e.: o1, o2, o3, o4, o5. All those 5 set have 10 similar variables.  I want to distinguish data set o1 to the other four data set but only want to use 3 variable to do so. How should I do it?  Is PCA is the right tool for that?  If yes, should I do the PCA for concatenation of all data set or should I do the PCA in pairs (i.e.: o1-02, o1-3, o1-o4, o1-o5)?
I don't know the name of this problem, so its kind of difficult for me to search for solution on the internet.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what you mean by "distinguish". What do you actually want to do? Run a statistical test to check if all your data sets are equal or not? See if you can predict what data set an observation is coming from? Etc.

Comment: Hi @amoeba I want to set up an outlier detector with o1 as the 'normal' base model.  The thing is, this will be just a sub modul of a bigger system, and I have to trim the variable as the processing requirement. o2, o3, o4, o5 are just other common phenomenon (and also other more rare scenario) that need to differentiate from o1.  Using current sample data, I need to find three variables out of ten that strongly distinguish o1 from the other, so when new data captured, the system using that three variable can 'easily' detect whether it is within the same characteristic with o1 or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PCA is not very appropriate, because PCA does not involve any kind of discrimination between classes. Instead, look at [Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis). LDA looks for a linear combination of features (like PCA does) but it looks for the combination that will separate classes, e.g. to separate your o1 from your o2 o3 o4 o5.

Your problem isn't described in much detail but it may be that the whole world of classification algorithms (and feature selection for classification) is useful to look at.